# What does colon mean between function inputs

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to calculate a function, but I am a bit confused with F(x,y:U,s) notation,

$$g\left( {x,y:\theta ,f} \right) = \exp \left\{ { - \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\frac{{x_\theta ^2}}{{\sigma _x^2}} + \frac{{y_\theta ^2}}{{\sigma _y^2}}} \right]} \right\}\cos \left( {2\pi f \cdot {x_\theta }} \right).$$

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: Sometimes a semicolon is used to distinguish between lists of different types of arguments (hypergeometric functions for instance). I can't recall seeing a colon though.

Comment: I am working on xy plane and i would like to draw some graph with that formula. x and y are the coordinates, u is angle of the lines, s is the frequency of the line.(also see, gabor filter) Thank you

Comment: @Caglar: in what function are the colons encountered?

Comment: Gabor filter, first term of it by Gaussian

Answer (score 2):

> What does colon mean between function inputs

It separates arguments $x,y$ which are coordinates from $\theta,f$ which are  thought of as parameters (angle and frequency). This is done merely for convenience of reading; the colon has no effect on the mathematical nature of the function.

As anon observed, it's more common to use the semi-colon `;` for this purpose. Indeed, this is what the [Gabor filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter) Wikipedia article does.

To plot the graph, you pick fixed values for everything after the colon, and plot the function of $x$ and $y$ only. The result should look like this heat plot from the aforementioned Wikipedia article: wave front in the middle, quickly fading due to the Gaussian factor.

[image]